# Angular 7, implementing Jstree

Tags: angular, jstree

I want to install jstree in my angular 7 project.
I followed this tutorial https://dotnetdetail.net/how-to-add-treeview-in-angular-6-and-asp-net-core-application/

I have some problems.
I think jstree is well installed, but i'm not sure it is well initialized,
I tested two methods :
the first one with html data
and the other one with javascript array

this is my reproducible example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anjn4e

on my DOM i just have my first item , the others are push in the data but doesn't appear.

I don't have any console error so i think it's just a logic problem

thanks for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Inside your project in Angular :**

```
npm install --save jquery jstree

npm install --save-dev @types/jquery @types/jstree
```

**Add into angular.json:**

```
styles: 
"node_modules/jstree/dist/themes/default/style.min.css"

scripts: 
"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
"node_modules/jstree/dist/jstree.min.js"
```

**Example in your component.html:**

```
    <div id="jstree">
    
        <ul>
            <li>Root node 1
                <ul>
                    <li id="child_node_1">Child node 1</li>
                    <li>Child node 2</li>
                </ul>
        </li>
            <li>Root node 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button>demo button</button>
```

**In your component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'tree';
  ngOnInit(): void {
    $(function () {
    // 6 create an instance when the DOM is ready
    $('#jstree').jstree();
    // 7 bind to events triggered on the tree
    $('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
      console.log(data.selected);
    });
    // 8 interact with the tree - either way is OK
    $('button').on('click', function () {
      $('#jstree').jstree(true).select_node('child_node_1');
      $('#jstree').jstree('select_node', 'child_node_1');
      $.jstree.reference('#jstree').select_node('child_node_1');
    });
  });
  }

}
```

Comment: Getting this error : error TS2339: Property 'jstree' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.

Comment: @ImranKhan try to import jquery to the component class: 
`import * as $ from 'jquery';`
`import 'jstree';`